# In C++, how can I get an arbitrary function's type from its declaration?

Tags: c++, templates, boost, c++11, metaprogramming

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Extract the return type of a function without calling it (using templates?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2005794/extract-the-return-type-of-a-function-without-calling-it-using-templates)

Starting with this (provided by somebody else):

```
int my_function(int, int *, double);
```

I want to get to this:

```
typedef boost::function_types::result_type< my_function_type >::type my_result;
typedef boost::function_types::parameter_types< my_function_type >::type my_parameters;
```

How do I get `my_function_type`?

NOTE: I know about `BOOST_TYPEOF()`, but it seems a bit scary, as in "perhaps not totally portable"?

Comment: Can the function be overloaded, or are you explicitly not wanting to handle that situation? Oh, and you'll probably need C++11 anyway.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: I can specify that the function is pure "C" style, and thus is not overloaded.

Comment: The C++11 keyword `decltype` would allow you to do so. I don't think there's any simple way to do it with just C++03.

Comment: @DavidH: I realise you are still waiting for an answer. Are you looking for a C++03 solution?

Comment: @phresnel: yes, that was the idea, though I'm getting convinced it's not possible.

Comment: @DavidH: Hmm, it wasn't mentioned anywhere that you are looking for an outdated standard solution. I think because of that, and the answerers assumed you are not restricted to C++03, you should accept an answer sooner or later :)

Comment: @phresnel: Fair enough, though some of us are still stuck in the past (or at least our compilers are).

Comment: @David H: Truly. Probably not at home where you have root control :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`decltype`. Examples:

```
char foo(int) {}
decltype (foo(3)) const *frob = "hello foo";
typedef decltype (foo(3)) typeof_foo;
using typeof_foo = decltype(foo(3));
```

The expression to `decltype` is evaluated at compile time and thus must be resolvable. You could pass any `constexpr` integer to it.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you want to do. Inside the body of

```
template <typename T>
void foo(T )
{
  // ...
}
```

T is the type of your function if you call `foo(my_function)`. Your problem cannot be solved using c++03-features, otherwise `decltype` wouldn't have been added to the core language.

Answer (score 1):

Here comes the template magic (no `Boost` is involved):

```
template <typename ReturnType> class clFunc0
{
    typedef ReturnType ( *FuncPtr )();
public:
    typedef ReturnType Type;
};

template <typename ReturnType> inline clFunc0<ReturnType> ResultType( ReturnType ( *FuncPtr )() )
{
    return clFunc0<ReturnType>();
}

#define FUNC_TYPE( func_name ) decltype( ResultType( &func_name ) )::Type

int test()
{
    return 1;
}

int main()
{
    FUNC_TYPE( test ) Value = 1;

    return Value;
}
```

And compile it via

```
gcc Test.cpp -std=gnu++0x
```

Comment: Still using decltype though, which seems to be the consensus of the earlier answers

Comment: To be honest like a programmer: Why not just reduce your code to `int test(){return 1;} int main() {decltype (test()) v = 1; return v;}`?