# Extracting return type from function template type

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I have a wrapper function similar to the following:

```
template<typename Func, typename ... Args>
void func(Func f, Args ... args) {
  ...
  f(args...);
  ...
}
```

Is it possible to extract the return type from the type `Func` at compile time?

For example, a user has the code and calls `func` in the following manner:

```
template<typename T>
T add(const T& l, const T& r) {
  return l + r;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  double a = 4.5, b = 5.5;
  func(add<double>, a, b);
  return 0;
}
```

Can we infer in the invocation of `func` that a function was passed to it which returns a `double`? I would like to use the return type information for other things inside `func`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Extract the return type of a function without calling it (using templates?)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2005794/extract-the-return-type-of-a-function-without-calling-it-using-templates)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Extracting the return type from an overloaded function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7260561/extracting-the-return-type-from-an-overloaded-function)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Either of the following should work

```
using result_type = decltype(std::declval<Func>()(std::declval<Args>()...));
```

or

```
using result_type = typename std::result_of<Func(Args...)>::type;
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6cf23fa5c9e4818d)

Comment: Beautiful, thank you.  In response, will it be an issue if I have a function with return type of `void` and have `return f(args...);` in `func` (obviously changing the return type of `func` to use your suggestion)?

Comment: Looks like it isn't a compilation issue! http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fcebfa729e050c95

Comment: @AlexBrooks No, not a problem, [works just fine](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/620cc4b1f1338031). You should also look into *universal references* and *perfect forwarding* (search SO for those terms, there are several answers dealing with them)

Answer (score 2):

Since c++17 it's [`std::invoke_result`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/result_of):

```cpp
using result_type = typename std::invoke_result_t<Func(Args...)>;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to C++14, or just out of curiosity, try not to commit to a particular type. 
The following code uses a generic lambda and the type is deduced for you. 
In many cases I find it much easier to work with.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<typename Func, typename ... Args>
void func(Func&& f, Args ... args) {
  return;
}

auto add = [](auto l, auto r) { return l * r; };

int main() 
{
    auto a = double{4.5};
    auto b = double{5.5};
    func(add, a, b);
    return 0;
}
```

Ideone:
http://ideone.com/wXnc0g